# Setting alarm with elapsed time type prints an inaccurate delay from dmesg in the kernel

Tags: android, kernel, alarmmanager

Can someone please explain me this time stamp discrepancy in the kernel log?

We wrote an app to wake up Android at a specified time and the app leverages `AlarmManager` API and sets:

```
AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
```

The app works as intended and wakes up at an user specified time correctly. But there is a discrepancy in the kernel timestamp. I traced the source code from `AlarmManagerService.java` to `alarm-dev.c` and confirmed that Android sets the alarm wake up time correctly and sends it to the kernel (eg. from Java layer Android uses `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` to get elapsed time and adds 100 sec and converts the value in second and nano second and finally sends it to the kernel layer through JNI).

However, when reading `dmesg` log it appears that there is a discrepancy in the kernel timestamp. At the time when `alarm_ioctl` function with the state `ANDROID_ALARM_SET(0):` was called `dmesg` printed the following message:

```
[20450.036529] alarm 2 set 20544.720000000
```

This implies that `[20450.036529]` is the current time and `20544.720000000` is when `AlarmManager` wakes Android up. The value `20544.720000000` was set from the Android layer and from the logcat's timestamp (eg. `logcat -v time`) this value is when Android is supposed to wake up.

From the Android layer to the kernel layer it takes less than a tenth of a second but why the delta is `94.683471`, which is `5.316529` less than it should be? Or is elapsed time different from the kernel time printed by `dmesg`?

Another interesting observation is that as written above, the app does wake up at a user specified time. So in this case after user called the app `AlarmManager` woke up the tablet in 100 sec.

Thank you,

References:

- [`AlarmManagerService.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/AlarmManagerService.java)
- [`alarm-dev.c`](https://github.com/TripNRaVeR/enrc2b-jb-3.1.10-endeavoru/blob/master/drivers/rtc/alarm-dev.c)

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1**

You might want to embed a timestamp inside the message instead of relying on the timestamp generated by printk(). This approach should at least give you a true measure of the time.

**OPTION 2**

You could investigate the API used by **kernel/printk.c** to get the timestamp.

If *printk* is using cpu_clock() You might want to consider the following:

[CPU Clock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/clock.c#L14)

```
 14  * What:
 15  *
 16  * cpu_clock(i) provides a fast (execution time) high resolution
 17  * clock with bounded drift between CPUs. The value of cpu_clock(i)
 18  * is monotonic for constant i. The timestamp returned is in nanoseconds
```